# Launchpad login issues

Tags: launchpad

This should almost certainly be on Meta. Apologies, I had to create a new account to submit this question because of the issues below. Can a moderator please move this?

Stack Exchange appears to have automatically logged me out of Ask Ubuntu.   When I attempt to log in, using Launchpad, it creates a new token on Launchpad and claims that token:

List of authorized tokens showing Ask Ubuntu as the application in the "Claimed token" section:

[image: List of Authorized Tokens showing Ask Ubuntu as the application in the "Claimed token" section.]

I also got an email from Launchpad confirming the token creation:

Email showing "A new OAuth token consumer was enabled in Launchpad.":

[image: Email showing "A new OAuth token consumer was enabled in Launchpad."]

(I tried going to irc.libera.chat but the website seems to time out.   I haven't tried (re)installing an IRC client yet.)

However it always returns me to the same page that says "Launchpad Login failed.  Please try logging in again.":

[image: "Launchpad Login failed. Please try logging in again."]

I have tried:

1. Disabling all ad blockers
2. Clearing the cache
3. Accepting all cookies on both sites
4. Changing the token access all the way up to "Change private data"
5. Attempting to log in through Incognito mode
6. Deleting all other Launchpad Tokens (both claimed and unclaimed)
7. Using Firefox (instead of Chrome)
8. Waiting a couple of days

This is, of course, all on Ubuntu.  I haven't tried from Windows (puke) or MacOS (lol).

**Is the Launchpad login broken?**

Comment: Also FYI as you appear to not be aware; Moderators are on *strike* (see https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/20325/stack-exchange-general-moderation-strike-the-effects-on-ask-ubuntu and other links) thus the extra spam, off-topic posts etc currently on this site recently, slower responses etc...

Comment: @guiverc Thanks.  Yes, I'm aware of how IRC works, but the email doesn't mention an IRC client, only a domain, and normally an IRC domain has a website at the very least.  Some even have anonymous web IRC clients these days.  The fact that it doesn't even have a website when it's mentioned in an automatic response is unhelpful, IMHO considering how little IRC is used by the general public these days, but that's nothing to do with SE, just an odd thing in passing from LP but also suggests to me that maybe something about LP is possibly broken or changed.

Comment: I, too, only log in when I need to, but obviously something expired forcing me to re log in and now I can't.  :-(

Comment: 3 weeks later and it's still the same. :-(

Comment: Four months and I can't log in with Launchpad. I also have an email/password combo saved so I got in, but it would be nice if Launchpad worked!

Comment: I reported bug about this on `Launchpad` bugtracker: - ["Launchpad Login Failed. Please try logging in again." error when trying to login to askubuntu.com](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/2048662)
Please, follow the link and press `This bug affects you` button.

Answer (score 0):

Bug about this on `Launchpad` bugtracker:

["Launchpad Login Failed. Please try logging in again." error when trying to login to askubuntu.com](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/2048662)

Please, follow the link and press `This bug affects you` button.